# Why Gdiplus::Graphics object assigned to the pointer data member in the constructor does not draw on TImage or TPaintBox objects?

Tags: c++, c++builder, gdi+

I don't understand why the `Gdiplus::Graphics` object assigned to the pointer data member in the constructor draws on the `TForm` object, but does not draw on the `TImage` or `TPaintBox` objects? However, the `Gdiplus::Graphics` object draws well on `TImage` or `TPaintBox` objects provided that the `Gdiplus::Graphics` object was assigned to the pointer data member before calling `Gdiplus::Graphics` functions for drawing.

Here is the code:

```cpp
__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput GdiplusStartupInput;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&mGdiplusToken, &GdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    // If the Gdiplus::Graphics object is created and assigned to pointer data member here it draws on TForm but does not draw on //TImage or TPaintBox
    //  mGraph = new Gdiplus::Graphics{Image1->Canvas->Handle};
}

void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Gdiplus::Status Status;

    Gdiplus::Color Red {Gdiplus::Color::Red};
    Gdiplus::Color Blue {Gdiplus::Color::Blue};
    Gdiplus::Color Green {Gdiplus::Color::Green};

    Gdiplus::Pen RedPen{Red, 2};
    Gdiplus::Pen BluePen{Blue, 2};
    Gdiplus::Pen GreenPen{Green, 2};

    Gdiplus::Graphics Graph1{Image1->Canvas->Handle};
    Gdiplus::Graphics* Graph2 = new Gdiplus::Graphics{Image1->Canvas->Handle};

    Status = Graph1.DrawLine(&RedPen, 50, 50, 100, 50);
    Status = Graph2->DrawLine(&BluePen, 50, 100, 100, 100);

    //If Gdiplus::Graphics object is created and assigned to the pointer data member here it draws on TForm or TImage or TPaintBox 
    mGraph = new Gdiplus::Graphics{Image1->Canvas->Handle};
    Status = mGraph->DrawLine(&GreenPen, 50, 150, 100, 150);

    Image1->Repaint();
}
```

Comment: I think the question may be improved showing where `mGraph` is declared and instantiated and indicating in the code the lines that don't work as you expect.

Comment: Does `Image1` actually hold a non-empty `TBitmap` at the time you request its `Handle`? If not, then the `TImage` will create a blank bitmap.  Gdi+ won't resize the bitmap, only draw on it.  So, if the bitmap is empty, there is nothing for Gdi+ to draw on. So make sure the bitmap has the required dimensions beforehand.

Comment: On a side note, your `Button1Click()` is leaking `Graph2`. You need to add a call to `delete Graph2;` when you are done using `Graph2`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. Image1 was created at design time.  Does it hold a blank bitmap in such a case? What is the definition of a blank bitmap?  Dimensions equal to zero?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why does it not needed to adjust the bitmap sizes when I have the statement `mGraph = new Gdiplus::Graphics{Image1->Canvas->Handle};` not in the constructor but in the event handler or any other member function?

Comment: @maksim_volodin did you put a picture into the TImage at design-time, and was it a BMP picture? If not, then no, the TImage will not have a valid non-empty bitmap at runtime, unless you assign one manually in code. But if you want to draw an image manually at runtime, you can draw onto an in-memory TBitmap first and the Assign() it to the TImage. Or, just draw on a TPaintBox in its OnPaint event.